# Ext.Js 1.0 Transaction Aborted Message keeps appearing. How to disable it?

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I am using Ext.Js version 1.0 and I keep getting Transcation Aborted after 30 seconds of pressing a button.  I want to completely disable timeout functionality of direct/ajax events.  how do I acheieve it?

I have a Default.aspx page and two other pages.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the timeout functionality of ajax events. I am not sure if you can completely disable it. If you disable it, how will you handle error? Did you have a look at why you are getting the timeout?

You can definitely increase the timeout for the Ajax event using the `timeout` property. Even the forms have the timeout property. You can set it in `BasicForm`. But note that for ajax, the value for timeout is in milliseconds and for form, its in seconds.

I suggest you really look into solving the issue of getting the timeout rather than extending the timeout.

Comment: SQL Connection is left opened for longer than 30 secs and that's because I want it to be open and not timeout. Is there a way to increase connection's timeout in ext?

Comment: that is what i have explained above. Use the timeout property to increase the connection's timeout!

Comment: To infinite? As thats the requirement and i want to do to all methods at once